# set_query_params using custom params defined in functions file?

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, rest-api

I am using the Advanced Custom Fields and [ACF to REST API](https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api) plugins. In my functions file I have specified custom query parameters to filter my custom post type by ACF fields in my REST request:

```
add_filter('rest_product_query', function($args) {
  $fields = array('size', 'color');

  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (isset( $_GET[ $field ]) && ! empty($_GET[$field])) {
      $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key'   => $field,
        'value' => esc_sql($_GET[$field]),
      );
    }
  }
  return $args; 
});
```

This part is working great when I go directly to the REST API url in my browser ie:

https://example.com/wp-json/acf/v3/product?per_page=100&size=large&color=blue

However, I am now trying to make a request to this URL using [WP_REST_Request()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_request/), but when I pass my custom parameters into the call, they are ignored. Here is what that code looks like:

```
$request = new WP_REST_Request('GET', '/acf/v3/product');
$request->set_query_params(
    ['per_page' => 100],
    ['size' => 'large'],
    ['color' => 'blue']
);
$response = rest_do_request($request);
$server = rest_get_server();
$data = $server->response_to_data($response, false);
$json = wp_json_encode($data);
echo count($data); // this returns 57 instead of the expected 15
```

When I go directly to the URL, 15 products are returned, but when I echo the `count` of the `WP_REST_Request()` response I am getting 57 results(all of the products). If I change the `per_page` parameter, it correctly returns the number of results I restrict it to, so it just seems to be ignoring only the custom parameters I have defined in my functions file.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it just seems to be ignoring only the custom parameters I have defined
> in my functions file

There are two issues in your code:

1. [`WP_REST_Request::set_query_params()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_request/set_query_params/) actually accepts just one parameter, which is an array of arguments, so your code should look like so:

   ```php
   $request->set_query_params([ // pass a single array containing one or more arguments
       'per_page' => 100,
       'size'     => 'large',
       'color'    => 'blue',
   ]);
   ```
2. I could see that you're using the [`rest_<post type>_query` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/) which has a second parameter named `$request` which is a `WP_REST_Request` instance, so in your filter function, instead of using `$_GET[ $field ]`, you should use `$request[ $field ]` (or you could also use the `$request->get_param( $field )` method) like so:

   ```php
   // 1. Make sure your function accepts the 2nd parameter:
   add_filter('rest_post_query', function($args, $request) {
     $fields = array('size', 'color');

     foreach ($fields as $field) {
       // 2. Use $request[ $field ] and not $_GET[ $field ].
       if (! empty($request[$field])) {
         $args['meta_query'][] = array(
           'key'   => $field,
           'value' => esc_sql($request[$field]),
         );
       }
     }

     return $args;
   }, 10, 2); // 3. Note the 3rd parameter (number of arguments for your function).
   ```

   And the reason why should the `$request` be used than relying upon the `$_GET` or `$_POST` superglobal, is because `WP_REST_Request` actually makes an *internal* API request, so no HTTP connections would be made, and unless the current URL (the page where you run `new WP_REST_Request`) contains the `size` or `color` parameter as in `example.com/some-page/?color=white`, then in your filter function, `$_GET['color']` for example would be undefined (not set).

   On the other hand, `$request['color']` or `$request->get_param( 'color' )` would always give you the correct value, regardless the current URL above contained `color` or not in the query string, so long as your query parameters actually contained the `color` parameter (and other necessary parameters). (see the `set_query_params()` above)

   So during a REST API request, always use the `$request` to access the query parameters.

And actually, this part:

```php
$server = rest_get_server();
$data = $server->response_to_data($response, false);
```

can simply be written as:

```php
$data = $response->get_data();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation, this is working perfectly!

Comment: Glad it helped! But sorry, that `// 3. Note the 3rd parameter` should actually be `// 3. Note the 4th parameter`..